# Can I databind to DataGridRow.DetailsVisibility?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpfdatagrid, rowdetailstemplate

I have a WPF datagrid control with a RowDetailsTemplate. I would like to be able to set a property on an object bound to the row to set whether that particular row should display details.

So for example if I have a basic layout like below and the "Detail" object had a boolean property called "Expanded" is there somewhere I can bind that property to have the details for its row show or not when the value changes?

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfDetailObjects}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!--My columns here-->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!--Details to show sometimes-->
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the [`DetailsVisibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridrow.detailsvisibility.aspx) in the [`DataGrid.RowStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowstyle.aspx).

Comment: Something like this worked. Thanks! `<DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Setter Property="DetailsVisibility" Value="{Binding Expanded, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" />    
                </Style>                
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>`